# What does it mean for a quotient ring to be finite

Tags: ring-theory

This is probably a really simple question, but I couldn't find any equivalent definitions for it online:

what do we mean when we say that a Quotient ring is finite? Does it simply mean that that set is finite?

Comment: yes. it means: there are finite elements; note that if $a-b\in I$ then $a+I=b+I$. so it is possible that $R$ be infinite and $R/I$ be finite.

Comment: Easy example to the previous comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite, $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ consists of integers modulo $n$ and is finite (containing $n$ elements).